# Excel Help - If Cell A1 = "123456", Cell B = "Product Description"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with setting up a formula so that excel produces a product description in one cell if the PO number is entered in the previous cell...

I.e if cell A1 = 123456 then I need Cell be to produce the product description "TELEPHONE" I would need this formula so that I can add additional PO's and products descriptions as we have 100+ items and I don't wish to keep typing the product name when I can hopefully use the PO number in the previous cell?

Comment: It's called a VLOOKUP

Answer (score 1):

1. Store all your product description and its code in say sheet 'Data'.
2. use the below formula in cell B1 and copy the same on all required cells in B column

`=IF(A1="","", VLOOKUP(A1,Data!A:B,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think I need some more help, I need the PO# to be entered into Cell A:A and then the product description auto fill into cell B:B

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you want to use **[if()](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/IF-function-a918d97a-251e-4af5-bd15-09b12b8742bb)** function.

And most likely you want to know if in cell A there is number. For that you can use function **[isnumber()](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/ISNUMBER-Function-DAX-02d5fa9a-c0db-4209-9147-480547e8b5c0?ui=en-US&rs=en-SG&ad=SG)**.

Example of function:

```
=if( isnumber(A1), "TELEPHONE", "" )
```

If you want to check for different descriptions, instead of "", add another if() function.

If you are checking for full match, use **[vlookup()](https://support.office.com/en-SG/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65)** insted of **if()**.

P.S. To be honest it is hard to understand, your problem.